# Permutations of Intersections of Parabola and Circles

Tags: permutations

What is the maximum number of points of intersection for four distinct parabolas and three distinct circles drawn on a sheet of paper?

Anyone good enough to solve this.?

Well considering the two different parabolas can intersect at 4 different points. WHen you bring a third one in, its even more.

Two circles intersecting bring 2 points. A circle and a parabola brings 4 I guess. So how many in total?

Answer (score 5):

6 times 4 parabola-parabola intersections, 12 times 4 parabola-circle intersections, 3 times 2 circle-circle intersections.

[image]

Comment: Nice!${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: How did you make it?

Comment: @samjoe Er, by thinking. First looking for ways to intersect the parabolas.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I meant which application :|

Comment: @samjoe: MS Word (the parabolas are actually Beziers).

Answer (score 1):

All pairs can potentially intersect in $4$ points, except for the pairs of circles, which can only have two intersection points.

It follows that an upper bound on the number of intersection points is 
$$4{\binom{4}{2}}+4(4\cdot 3)+2\binom{3}{2}=78$$
Explanation:

- ${\large{\binom{4}{2}}}$ pairs of parabolas, each pair with at most $4$ intersection points.

  $4{\,\cdot\,}3$ parabola-circle pairs, each pair with at most $4$ intersection points.

  $\binom{3}{2}$ pairs of circles, each pair with at most $2$ intersection points.

I see no reason why the upper bound is not achievable.

Comment: My mistake!!, Sorry

Comment: Your answer is correct, but some work is needed in the explanation part! +1

Comment: @samjoe: Thanks. I fixed the typos in the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Total number of intersections of parabolas is 24. For any two parabolas there is 4 intersections. There is 4C2 ways to choose 2 parabolas out of 4. 4C2 x 4 = 24.

For a circle and a parabola, the maximum number of intersections is 4. 
Total number of intersections of circles and parabolas is 4x4x3=48

For any two circles, the maximum number of intersections is 2.

Total intersections of circles is 3C2 x 2 =6

Maximum total is 24+48+6=78

Comment: Why did you answer your own question?

Answer (score -1):

Four parabolas can have a maximum of 24 points of intersection.  A circle can have four points of intersection with a parabola and hence 16 with four parabolas. Three circles can have have 48 points of intersection.

Each circle can intersect other circle at 2 points and three circles can intersect with each other at 6 points and hence I revise it to be 78.

Comment: Very close :) :)

Comment: Two parabolas can intersect in at most 4 points, and there are 6 pairs of parabolas. How can you achieve 32 ??

Comment: Fixed it, my apologies!!